# How to eliminate duplicate values and format the output from DQL in Twig?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, group-by, twig

I am working on a reporting application in Symfony2, and my twig file shows the following output using DQL. I created an Entity, passed the values using render from action function to the twig. I used a for loop to display all the elements from an associative array (See picture 1). how do I group the result in this specific format? (See picture 2) such that all the duplicate zoneName and rank are eliminated and placed on the top only once.

### Current Display of records in twig FROM DQL

[image: Current Display of records in twig FROM DQL]

### The output which I want to achieve

[image: The output which I want to achieve]
My query in Action function of controller is as follows

```
     $qb->select('distinct t.zoneName, t.rank, t.actSanctList, t.offDate')
            ) /*, $dql */

        ->addGroupBy('t.zoneName')     
        ->addGroupBy('t.rank')    
         ->addGroupBy('t.actSanctList')   
        ->addGroupBy('t.offDate')  

        ->orderBy('t.zoneName', 'ASC')

        $DL01 = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

My twig file

```
                  {% for DL01_line in DL01_data %}

                        <tr>
                        <td>{{ DL01_line.zoneName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ DL01_line.rank }}</td>                                          
                        <td>{{ DL01_line.actSanctList }}</td>
                         <td>{{ DL01_line.offDate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                                </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
```